# Django: How to query based on a ForiegnKey and display related data for each ForeignKey?

Tags: python, django

I am brand new to Django and to programming and I'm trying to make a page that will display the Workout with all the associated Exercises listed under each work out.

For example:

**Chest**

Chest Press
Incline Press
Flat Flyes

**Shoulders**

Shoudler Press
Arnold Press

**Back/Legs**

Wide Grip Pull Up
Neutral Grip Pull Up
Bent Over Row

Here is my code:

models.py

```
class Workout(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Exercise(models.Model):
workout = models.ForeignKey(Workout, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='workouts')
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
weight = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=0, max_digits=10000)
date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

views.py

```
    def home(request):
    context = {
        'workouts': Workout.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'workouts/home.html', context)

def workout(request):
    context = {
        'workouts': Workout.objects.all(),
        'exercises': Exercise.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'workouts/workout.html', context)
```

workout.html

```
{% extends 'workouts/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    {% for workout in workouts %}
        <h1>{{ workout.title }}</h1>
        {% for exercise in exercises %}
            <h3>{{ exercise.title }}</h3>
            <p>{{ exercise.weight }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

In my view.py I have it set to Exercise.objects.all() which just displays all of the exercises under each Workout title, I can figure out how to get only the exercises that are associated with the Workout.

Like I said I am brand new to all of this and I'd appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define property to Workout model to retrieve exercises related to the instance. Just add a new method with property decorator to retrieve Exercises related with that Workout.

```
class Workout(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    @property
    def exercises(self):
        return self.workouts.all()
```

Then you can use exercises in your html file like:

```
{% extends 'workouts/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    {% for workout in workouts %}
        <h1>{{ workout.title }}</h1>
        {% for exercise in workout.exercises %}
            <h3>{{ exercise.title }}</h3>
            <p>{{ exercise.weight }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Another approach may be grouping Exercises with workouts in your view and pass them to template. For more information, you can check [regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup)

When you define FK relationship between two models, Django adds a manager to target model to query related objects. When you use this manager, you basicly run a query something like `Exercise.objects.filter(workout_id=workout_instance_id)`. This is a queryset, so you can join with features of queryset features like `filter`, `first` and `extra`. You can use a plenty of queryset features on related objects. This is basicly the power of Django ORM mechanism. You can find a bit more in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) if you need to.

Comment: When I try this I get: 'Workout' object has no attribute 'exercise_set'

Comment: My bad, I didn't noticed that you override related_name on FK. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Awesome! Totally worked gonna have to research a bit as to how it works cause I still don't totally understand. Thank you!
Also... would this be considered the "right" way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Glad that it works. I have updated my answer to help you about mechanism of Django ORM. I hope that also help you.